# Override non-identifier property from the base class and make it an identifier in the subclass

Tags: java, jpa

I am having a problem. When trying to inherit from an parent class an attribute that is not defined as an identifier, but in my child class yes, the following error occurs:

> MappingException: You cannot override the [testDate] non-identifier
>   property from the [com.test.BaseEntity] base class or
>   @MappedSuperclass and make it an identifier in the
>   [com.test.ChildEntity] subclass!

My parent class:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE_UTC")
    protected Timestamp testDate;

    public Timestamp getTestDate() {
        return testDate;
    }

    public void setTestDate(Timestamp testDate) {
        this.testDate = testDate;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        testDate = Timestamp.from(Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
    }
}
```

My child class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Entity(name = "CHILD")
@IdClass(ChildEntityPk.class)
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4392848588125748902L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_TEST_DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Timestamp testDate;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTestDate() {
        return testDate;
    }

    public void setTestDate(Timestamp testDate) {
        this.testDate = testDate;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the super class?

Comment: The BaseEntity? Yes

Comment: Why are you making "testDate" protected in scope?

Comment: Honestly, I am just starting to work with this code and I had not noticed that detail. It doesn't make sense for him to be protected, but that's not the problem anyway

Comment: Try making it private and attempt your mapping again.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Facing same issue. Anybody have a solution please ?